# React, how to restore page after browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react and material-ui to create a simple search form.
After entering the values for the search on page A (text input box, drop-down list, checkbox), the results are displayed on page B.
When I go to page B and come back to page A, how can I get page A to display with the first value entered?
I was able to use `useHistory()` `history.push` and `useEffect` to set the state to the value I initially entered, but the text input box, checkbox, and drop-down list remained refreshed and empty.
It uses checkboxes, selects, and text fields from material-ui.

On page A, I used `history.push` to transfer the value set on page A to page B, and when you return from page B to page A, I used `history.push` again on page B to transfer it to page A, and then used `useEffect` to set the value to state so that the first value I entered is used again on page A. I was able to use the first value I entered on page A again.

However, the value was only set programmatically, and the visible input form remained empty. How can I get back to having the value in the input form as well as the value in the program?

Comment: Could you please add the required code, so it will be helpful

Comment: You can use redux to save the states of the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the form data in the window.history.state before submitting the form by using [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)

This lets you store any value in the history state, which is accessible via `window.history.state` when you come back from Page B to Page A by clicking the back button.

Read more about history state: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API